# Change status with Javascript in MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I need your help. I have an auction scenario. I wrote two functions in javascript code. In this way, two counts are made according to the beginning and end of the auction. I want it to be "arac_durum" -> "Aktif" in my database when the first count is completed and "arac_durum" -> "Pasif" when the second count is completed. How can I do it, can you help?

```js
<script>

function createCountDown(elementId, date, dateiki) {

    var countDownDate = new Date(date).getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {


    var now = new Date().getTime();
    

    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    

    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    

    document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = "Süre ►" + days + ": " + hours + ": " + minutes + ": " + seconds;
    

    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);

        document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = "Started !";
        // Here I want the "arac_durum" item to be "Aktif".
        

        
        
        var bitistarihi = new Date(dateiki).getTime();
        var y = setInterval(function() {
            var simdi = new Date().getTime();
            var distance = bitistarihi - simdi;
            var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
            document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = "Süre ►" + days + ": " + hours + ": " + minutes + ": " + seconds;
            if (distance < 0) {
                clearInterval(y);

                document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = "Finish !";
                // Here I want the "arac_durum" item to be "Pasif".
                
                }
        }, 1000);
                
        
    }
}, 1000);

}

createCountDown("<?=$araccek['arac_id']?>", "<?=$araccek['arac_gerisayim']?>", "<?=$araccek['arac_tarih']?>")
  



</script>
```

```html
 <p id="<?=$araccek['arac_id']?>"></p>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's your specific problem with achieving your aim? If you want to send the new value to your database then first you need to send it to your server via a HTTP request, so that some PHP code can be executed to save the value into the database. A browser can trigger a HTTP request in a few ways - by the user clicking a link, by Javascript navigating the browser to a new URL, by the user submitting a form, by javascript submitting a form, or by making an AJAX request using Javascript. I would guess the last option is probably what you'll want.

Comment: Make a request using XMLHttpRequest / fetch for a suitable PHP script, and have the script update the DB row.

Comment: @Chris G Can you give me a sample update code?

Comment: `fetch('update.php?value=123')` will run `update.php` on the server, passing `$_GET['value'] = 123`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: You need a server side code to receive the flag,if flag is 1 update active, otherwise update pasif, let's crwate PHP file and name it - modify.php:

```
<?php
      $flag = $_POST['flag'];
      $id = 1; //You have to receive the value of the id from the client. I mean to passed with the ajax request.
      $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourdatabase";
      $pdo = new PDO($dsn, 'dbuser', 'userpassword');
       if( $flag == 1)
                $value = "active";
        else
                 $value = "passif";

         $stm = $pdo->prepare("Update yourTableName set arac_durum=? WHERE keyfield = ?");
         $stm->bindValue(1, $value);
         $stm->bindValue(2, $id);
    if( $stm->execute())
       echo "updated successfuly";
     else
        echo "error";
```

?>

Second: Use Jquery to write AJAX code in your javascript section to send  the status from the client to the server.

You are going to replace this comment by the ajax code
// Here I want the "arac_durum" item to be "Pasif".

Let's do it:

```
$.ajax({
           Type:'POST',
            url:'modify.php',
            data:{flag:2},
             success:function(response)
             {
                 // do sth here like alert a msg
                   alert(response);
             }
      });
```

Above solution is enough to fix your problem, but if you are not familiar with jquery you can use (fetch) appi  to send data from the client to the server.

```
 fetch('modify.php?flag=2')
         .then(reponse=>response.text())
         .then(data=>alert(data));
```

In modify.php use $_GET['flag'] instead of $_POST['flag'] because i added the parameter in the url of the page. The rest of code will remain as it is.

You can also use XMLHttpRequest object to transfer data between the browser and the server.

Comment: probably worth pointing out that this solution requires jQuery, which the OP has not mentioned they are using - and they may not want to add it just for one ajax request. Why not just propose a solution using fetch()?

Comment: Thanks. Yeah right, it is worth mentioning. However JQuery fixed the problem.

Comment: What I mean is you should edit your answer to explain that fact, especially in case others read this in future. Answers on this site are not aimed only at the person who originally asked the question...

Comment: @Samet to improve the quality of the answer, would you explain to me why did you changed your mind?

Comment: @Hardood
<?php
       //receive the value ( actif, pasif)
       $flag = $_POST['flag'];
       //database connection
       if( $flag == 1)
           //upadate active --actif
        else
           //update inactive --pasif
      //statement to update
      // response: echo "updated successfuly"..

Can you explain this part a little more?

Comment: Ok, you have tow comments in your javascript file, the first one is // Here I want the "arac_durum"  item to actif and the  second is // Here I want the "arac_durum" item to be "Pasif". So you have to replace the first comment with ajax code and set the flag to 1.  The second comment also must be replaced by ajax code and the value of flag is 2. in other words you have to write ajax twice, but both ajax codes must send to only one php file but with different value to flag parameter.

Comment: Regarding the PHP code ( server side ), you have to receive the value of the flag, if 1 received then you will update your column with active, if 2 then update the field by the passif value. I showed you where to write the database connection, and where to write the update statements but i didn't write the code of the database details, because i didn't know if you are using mysqli or PDO....etc.

Comment: As you can see i descriped the locations of database connection and update queries and the response to ajax request in a form of comments to give you a space to choose suitable database driver for your project, and i think you have chosen one before you ask your question, because you just asked for update. That is mean you have already inserted data in your database by using mysqli or PDO.

Comment: @Hardood Can you also tell me how to make modify.php file with PDO?

Comment: By the way, are you updating the entire table by active/passif at a time, or you just updating specific record/s based on a keyfield?

Comment: @Hardood I update according to the key field. I want the expired item to go into passive state. I get a warning because the update is successful. But the "arac_durum" status does not change to "Pasif". Because if he changed he would be invisible on my homepage.

Comment: How do you passed the keyfield from javascript?.

Answer (score 0):

Php and Js Code;

```js
<p id="<?=$araccek['arac_id']?>"></p>


<script>

function createCountDown(elementId, date, dateiki, durum) {

    var countDownDate = new Date(date).getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Sistem saatini alıyoruz
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    
    // Geri sayımla şimdi saat arasındaki zamanı ölçüyoruz
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    
    // Gün, Saat, Dakika, Saniye işlemleri yapılıyor
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    // Anlık olarak id="gerisayim" içine aktarılıyor
    document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = "Süre ►" + days + ": " + hours + ": " + minutes + ": " + seconds;
    
    
    
    
    // Süre dolduğunda yazacak yazı.
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);

        document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = "Başladı !";
        
        $.ajax({
           Type:'POST',
            url:'modify.php',
            data:{durum:2},
             success:function(response)
             {
                 // do sth here like alert a msg
                   alert(response);
             }
      });


        
        
        var bitistarihi = new Date(dateiki).getTime();
        var y = setInterval(function() {
            var simdi = new Date().getTime();
            var distance = bitistarihi - simdi;
            var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
            document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = "Süre ►" + days + ": " + hours + ": " + minutes + ": " + seconds;
            if (distance < 0) {
                clearInterval(y);

                document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = "Bitti !";
                
                $.ajax({
           Type:'POST',
            url:'modify.php',
            data:{durum:1},
             success:function(response)
             {
                 // do sth here like alert a msg
                   alert(response);
             }
      });
                
                }
        }, 1000);
                
        
    }
}, 1000);

}

createCountDown("<?=$araccek['arac_id']?>", "<?=$araccek['arac_gerisayim']?>", "<?=$araccek['arac_tarih']?>", "<?=$araccek['arac_durum']?>")
  



</script>
```

Modify.php;

```html
<?php
      $flag = $_POST['durum'];
      $id = 1; //You have to receive the value of the id from the client. I mean to passed with the ajax request.
      $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sametsarihan_db";
      $pdo = new PDO($dsn, 'sametsarihan_db', '********');
       if( $flag == 1)
                $value = "Aktif";
        else
                 $value = "Pasif";

         $stm = $pdo->prepare("Update araclar set arac_durum=? WHERE arac_id = ?");
         $stm->bindValue(1, $value);
         $stm->bindValue(2, $id);
    if( $stm->execute())
       echo "updated successfuly";
     else
        echo "error";
        
        ?>
```

My Database Table:

https://hizliresim.com/9J87vg

Comment: Instead of $id = 1, it must be $id = $_POST['id']; In your ajax code modify data :{ flag:1} to data:{flag:1, id:value}. value must be the real value of the key in your table.

Comment: $id = $_POST['arac_id'];
data: {flag: 1, id: elementId},
this way?

Comment: There will be no definite identity value. I add items with the foreach loop. No matter what item is currently added, it must be processed. I guess elementId provides this in js codes.

Comment: What is this : 
<p id="<?=$araccek['arac_id']?>"></p>

Comment: Try to add id parameter to ajax code like this: data:{flag:1,id:elementId},.......

Comment: In modify.php change $id = 1 to $id = $_POST['id'];

Comment: "<p id =" <? = $ Araccek ['arac_id']?> "> </p>" -> Prints the items I added from the admin panel to the page between the p tags. (It allows me to get data from the database)

Comment: Do you have the opportunity to contact Teamviewer, sir?

Comment: It is too hard now, beside that teamviewer app is not installed on my phone.

Comment: Çok teşekkür ederim dostum

Comment: My English is bad so I use translate :)

Comment: Kodu yazmayı ve test etmeyi deneyin, umarım bundan sonra uygulamanın ayrıntılarını söyleyebilirsiniz.

Comment: Hayır, hayır, bu arada İngilizcen mükemmel

Comment: Teşekkür ederim, I would be glad if you send a message :) 
Instagram: Bewsoft

Comment: @Hardood, Are you here ?